# Mysql code working in browser but not working when running page in mobile

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php file with mysql code in it, problem is that when I run that in chrome browser it file runs and mysql code also update the table but when I run the same file in mobile php file runs but mysql table is not updated
Php code is given below
    
         
          My site

```
<body>
<?php
require 'req.php';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$post_trans=$_POST["farm_option"];
mysql_select_db('abc');
$sql2 = "UPDATE table SET act_st='1' WHERE transaction='$post_trans'";
$sqlste = mysql_query($sql2, $conn);
if($sqlste){
    echo "<h1>Account Activated</h1>";
}
}else{
$sql ="SELECT transaction, email FROM `trans` WHERE act_st='0'";
mysql_select_db('abc');
$sqlst = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if($sqlst){
    echo '<form name="farm" method="post" action="nis.php">';
    echo '<label>transaction </label>';
echo '<select name="farm_option">';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlst)){
        echo '<option>'.$row['transaction'].'</option>';
                }
            echo '</select>';

            echo '<input type="submit">';
echo '</form>';}
}
?>
```

When I submit the form from mobile it print "Account Activated" but the table is not updated

Comment: Is `farm_option` set correctly? This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: While I know it isn't your question, I'd just like to let you know that `mysql_` is deprecated, and the code you've posted is incredibly vulnerable to injection.

Comment: Did you try to echo the value of your post inside the nis.php page? Do you see the values in both PC and mobile device ?

Comment: Yes I have done echo of farm_option, in browser it's show the value but not in mobile. I am just wondering that if in mobile it print "account activated" then why not it update the table?

Comment: First of all you should be using mysqli or pdo. This code needs rewriting. When something doesn't work break it down. Forget update and insert just start with a blank file and just make sure the update works first. When you know the update is working try the rest of the code. Sometimes I take the php line and paste it into phpmyadmin. It gives you more error information, and sometimes you can work out the problem easier. I can't answer your problem from what you have given though